# PreventDefault on null value

Tags: javascript, null, preventdefault

i am using this code to select an row(id) from a table then modify it in another page in case no row(id) was selected nothing should happen.

```
$('#modify').click(function (e) {
                var id = $.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
                    return item[0];
                });
                console.log(id);
                if (id === null) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    window.location = "<spring:url value='/secure/purchaseRequests/item/'/>" + id + "/modify";
                }
            });
```

I am printing the id value and it's null why the preventDefault is not working ?

Comment: Try preventing the default immediatly, so below the click functionality.

Comment: I can't think of a case where `id` was `null`. It might be an empty array, but that's something different.

Comment: I think you should check typeof(id) also if its string then this code wont work

Comment: I am putting the first item of array in variable var and checking if it's null . This part is working the value is null - Bergi

Comment: @Roli Agrawal Its an int

Comment: @Roberrrt Did that , same result .

Comment: What i'm assuming is that you're also clicking on a <a> below it, could you add e.stopPropagation() as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```
            $(document).on('click', "#modify", function(e) {  
                var id = $.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
                    return item[0];
                });
                console.log(id);
                if (id === null) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    window.location = "<spring:url value='/secure/purchaseRequests/item/'/>" + id + "/modify";
                }
            });
```

Comment: You need to stop the propagation of the click event up the DOM to the a element, and also prevent the default behaviour of the link

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution , apparently the value id is not null , it's empty and preventDefault should be replaced by return false. So the checking only the existence of a value in id should be enough.

```
$('#modify').click(function (e) {
                var id = $.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
                    return item[0];
                });
                console.log(id);
                if (id) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    window.location = "<spring:url value='/secure/purchaseRequests/item/'/>" + id + "/modify";
                }
            });
```